# Думал зацепит, но пронесло

Tags: этимология, смысл

Как появился такой переносный смысл слова "пронести"? Правильно ли такое предположение: "провидение **пронесло** меня мимо беды"?

Comment: У Даля в словарной статье "Туча" есть такое: _На нас туча идет, гроза, беда, опасность. Грозную тучу Бог пронесет._ Я предполагаю, что "проносит" _мимо_ человека.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Смысл выражения:** Бог  пронёс опасность мимо человека, опасность миновала.

**Бог пронесёт** Прост. Может быть, удастся избежать опасности, неприятности, устранить беду.

Хоть Дубровский не раз приходил мне в голову, да думаю: город близко, всего 7 верст, авось **бог пронесёт**. Пушкин.http://www.frazeologiya.ru/fraza/pronosit.htm

**Пронесло** (безличный вариант): опасность, беда миновала (разг.).